# How to get text boxes for Gridview Row values?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Using C# & Mysql

In my webpage am using gridview, if i click the column in the girdview the value should display in the textbox.

For Example

Griview

```
Column1 column2 Column3

    1 Raja 9876
    2 Ravi 7890
    3 Ramu 9879
    ...
```

If i click the 2 rows all the values should display in the textbox

```
Textbox1.text = 2
textbox2.text = Ravi
textbox3.text = 9879
...,
```

How to write a code for this condition.

Need C# code Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that by stating "*[...]click the 2 rows[...]*" you actually mean "*click the 2nd row*"; at least, this is what your last snippet suggests, since it shows only the values of the 2nd row (on a little side note: the ID's wrong there; it should be `7890`).

The following code snippet shows a `GridView` which allows the selection of a single row, and uses an event handler in the code-behind to set the text of each `TextBox` to the according value in the selected row:

*Page.aspx*:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gridView" OnSelectedIndexChanged="gridview_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoGenerateSelectButton="true"></asp:GridView>
```

Event handler in the code-behind file *Page.aspx.cs*:

```
void gridview_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var grid = sender as GridView;
    if (grid == null) return;

    //Cell[0] will be the cell with the select button; we don't need that one
    Textbox1.Text = grid.SelectedRow.Cell[1].Text /* 2 */;
    Textbox2.Text = grid.SelectedRow.Cell[2].Text /* Ravi */;
    Textbox3.Text = grid.SelectedRow.Cell[3].Text /* 7890 */;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `EditItemTemplate` for this.

See the CodeProject article, *[Editable Gridview with Textbox, CheckBox, Radio Button and DropDown List](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/editable_gridview_control.aspx)*.